# Dynamic Grails Url Mapping config

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I dynamically build a list of mappings - instead of:

```
class UrlMappings {
static mappings = {
   "/helpdesk/user/$action?/$id?" (controller="helpdeskuser")
   "/helpdesk/group/$action?/$id?" (controller="helpdeskgroup")
   "/helpdesk/company/$action?/$id?" (controller="helpdeskcompany")
   "/helpdesk/account/$action?/$id?" (controller="helpdeskaccount")
   "/admin/company/$action?/$id?" (controller="admincompany")
   "/admin/account/$action?/$id?" (controller="adminaccount")
 }
}
```

something like this pseudo code:

```
class UrlMappings {
static mappings = {
   application.controllerClasses.each {
     if(it.name.startsWith('helpdesk'))
        "/helpdesk/${it.name}/$action?/$id?" (controller="${it.name}")
     if(it.name.startsWith('admin'))
        "/admin/${it.name}/$action?/$id?" (controller="${it.name}")
   }
 }
}
```

(I don't understand what the static mappings are - a hash map? free variables?)

What I am trying to achieve are mappings based on the controller type - e.g. helpdesk, admin or user controllers. Once I have set up the mappings I want to add security based on URLs but I don't want to map each controller individually:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/helpdesk/**':   ['ROLE_HELPDESK','ROLE_ADMIN'],
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just done the following in my application:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {        
    for( controllerClass in ApplicationHolder.application.controllerClasses) {
      // Admin Controllers first
      if( controllerClass.name.startsWith("Admin")){
        // note... fixes the case so that AdminUserController maps to /admin/user
        "/admin/${controllerClass.name[5].toLowerCase() + controllerClass.name[6..-1]}/$action?/$id?" {
          controller = "admin${controllerClass.name[5..-1]}".toString()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd not actually done this before, your question prompted me to fix this is my app. It's been one of those things I've been trying to do for a while.

Comment: Except that now <g:link controller="${c}"> and I guess controller redirect does not return the correct url.

Comment: mmm..it should <a href="${createLink(controller:'adminDashboard')}">Dashboard</a> in my app renders /admin/dashboard using the same code as above.

Comment: ApplicationHolder is deprecated now. Any thoughts on the best way to inject the application into `UrlMappings`?

Comment: Just been having a look and as far as I can see there isn't another way to get hold of the Application object. Injection doesn't work as the mappings closure is static and won't have access to any injected values.

Comment: To anybody coming across this now, current version of Grails allow you to inject `grailsApplication` as usual into URLMappings (with `def grailsApplication`).

Comment: `grailsApplication` in `UrlMappings` in Grails 2.x can be achieved with `Holders.getGrailsApplication()` as mentioned in [this conversation](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Access-grailsApplication-in-UrlMappings-td4635898.html). Alternatively you could use `grailsUrlMappingsHolder` (Grails 2.3+) to manage `UrlMappings` as in @Spider answer.

Answer (score 6):

The grailsUrlMappingsHolder bean is available in services and controllers. Although it's concrete implementation of UrlMappingsHolder doesn't have an add method, its superclass does. Simple as this in grails 2.3.4

```
def grailsUrlMappingsHolder

def addMapping() {        
    grailsUrlMappingsHolder.addMappings({
        "/admin"(controller:"admin" action:"index")  
    });        
}
```

Comment: This one is since 2.3 [source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/e1c225882e59d18814f0b6b03ef2586731ce20ad/grails-web-url-mappings/src/main/groovy/grails/web/mapping/UrlMappings.java)

Comment: Hi. Can I ask how can I invoke this on my `Bootstrap.groovy`, I have a little bit of a [problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42480608/4043409) and I think a little tweaking of this answer can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve something similar for my application and found a nice way provided by grails. It goes like

```
name admin: "/admin/$cName/$action/$id?" {
    controller = {
        "admin" + params.cName.capitalize()
    }
}
```

Watch out, this does not work if you use `$controller` vs. `$cName` (or whatever you like to have there) and will throw a NullpointerException instead.

As a bonus you can then use the mapping name like

```
<g:createLink 
    controller="adminBackend" action="login" 
    mapping="admin" params="[cName:'backend']"
/>
```

to get a link to /admin/backend/login - Hope this helps!

Stay fresh!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the `$controller` variable, see the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.2%20Embedded%20Variables).

```
static mappings = {
   "/helpdesk/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
}
```

BTW, the mappings to `controller`s and, optional, their `view`s are enclosed by normal brackets `()`, not curly ones `{}`.

Such Groovy Scripts (as *UrlMappings.groovy*) are parsed by a [`ConfigSlurper`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) instance, which finally converts them to a `ConfigObject` that `implements Map`. Admittedly, I'm either not sure how this parsing is accomplished in detail.

**EDIT**:

[Here](http://www.assembla.com/code/PlayForGood/subversion/nodes/p4g/grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy?rev=76)'s an *UrlMappings.groovy* that comes somewhat near to what you want. (Search for "/$_ctrl/$_action/$id?".) The code, BTW, gets evaluated at runtime. Nevertheless, I haven't been able to put the `grailsApplication` to work.

Another idea was to add a `javax.servlet.Filter` to the web application, i.e., by subclassing Grails' `UrlMappingsFilter`.

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer - I want to map it depending in the controller name or package etc e.g.:class UrlMappings {
static mappings = {
   application.controllerClasses.each {
     if (it.name.startsWith("help"))
        "/helpdesk/${it.name}/$action?/$id?" (controller="${it.name}")
  else if (it.name.startsWith("admin")){
        "/admin/${it.name}/$action?/$id?" (controller="${it.name}")
     }  
   }
 }
}

Comment: Thanks for the link - very flexible