# Use grailsApplication injection inside UrlMappings

Tags: grails, grails-controller

For some reason I get a huge list of errors when using following code:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static grailsApplication
    static mappings = {

    grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass -> // FAILS!
        println(controllerClass.name)
    }

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{}

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Errors: http://pastebin.com/tiEsENie

---

Where as following code works just fine and prints all the controller names:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static grailsApplication
static mappings = {

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass -> // WORKS!
            println(controllerClass.name)
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
}
```

Isn't it possible to access the static `grailsApplication` from inside `static mappings`?

(I need to be able to get the controller names in order to dynamically create urlmappings)

Comment: isn't using `$controller` essentially what you want? Why do you need to loop over the controllers and print them in the mappings anyway?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232884/dynamic-grails-url-mapping-config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232884/dynamic-grails-url-mapping-config)

Comment: because I want to split all ModeratorControllers into /mod/action

Comment: I looked into the given example but does not work since `ApplicationHolder` is deprecated in the current 2.0 release

Comment: It's deprecated, but it's still there and works fine.

Comment: have you looked at the source for the url mapping report generation? `./grailsw url-mappings-report` may give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

While `ApplicationHolder` still works, the grails docs state this for the in the deprecation comments

**deprecated:** Use dependency injection or implement GrailsApplicationAware instead

Since `grailsUrlMappingsHolderBean` implements `GrailsApplicationAware`, I found that the code below works in 2.0 as well

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {        
        getGrailsApplication().controllerClasses.each{ controllerClass -> 
            if(controllerClass.name./*your logic here*/){
                "/mod/action" {
                    controller = "${controllerClass.name}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this brings up an issue with my integration tests not working anymore.. could it be due to the fact that we are calling a nonstatic thing from a static environment?

Comment: Breaks my integration tests as well. Worked around by wrapping with if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {..}