# How to get controller name inside dynamic mapping closure

Tags: grails

I'm trying to get the controller name inside dynamic mapping closure like this:

```
"/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    controller = {
        "${controllerName}Admin"
    }
}
```

to force all requests to "/admin/[controller name]" be mapped to controllers named "[controller name]Admin". "controllerName" variable do work outside the closure, but inside don't.

How do I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232884/dynamic-grails-url-mapping-config) a similar SO question. Have you seen it already?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. I just want to know if there is a standard way to  get the controller name inside a dynamic mapping closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be:

```
    "/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        controller = {
            def controllerName = (request.requestURI - request.contextPath).split('/')[2]

            // or
            //def controllerName = request.servletPath.split('/')[2]

            "${controllerName}Admin"
        }
    }
```