# accessing variable in url mapping, grails

Tags: grails, url-mapping

i am trying to access the variable defined in url mapping to be used to generate a new url.

Tried something as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232884/dynamic-grails-url-mapping-config#answer-15543932), like:

```
name oldUri: "/somecontroller/$someparam"{
        controller = "newcontroller"
        action = "index"
        newURI = {
            "/data/" + params?.someparam
        }
    }
```

But getting NullPointer on params.
Is there a ways to get someparam variable in this mapping? 
I am using grails 2.2.2 version

FYI: The purpose of this mapping is to redirect a user from an old URL to a new URL. and that specific issue has been resolved in 2.3 http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5994

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Because in the link you posted, there is used dynamic controller name construction, in your case it's static. What is newURI closure for?

Comment: I am trying to add a backward compatibility of some obsolete urls, to redirect to newer ones. newUri will be the parameter variable to which we will redirect user

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're missing something here. The mapping of old controller url to the new controller is done simply by this: name oldUri: "/somecontroller" {
        controller = "newcontroller"
        } and new controller will receive all the params sent in the request..

Comment: Thanks Lukelazarovic for the reply. Actually, those url should be redirected to newer ones.. like somedomain.com/mydata to somedomain.com/data/mydata. By defining the controller="newcontroller" will just let grails know which controller and action to call but wont redirect. This specific problem is solved in 2.3 as per http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5994